# Problemas al reproducir un audio en visualStudio y CodePen / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

Tengo un problema al reproducir un enlace de audio en mi VisualStudio y también en el codePen.

```
<audio
          src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rpIU7p9QQxDWi2tEy9HQc6thvHH3qKpX/view?usp=sharing"
          type="audio.wav"
          autoplay
          controls
        ></audio>
```

Asi defini mi tag audio y no se reproduce, utilicé un audio que comparti a travez de Google Drive.

Al acceder al link el audio se reproduce con normalidad, cuando voy al editor ya no, aparece el boton de play bloqueado. ¿ Que podria estar faltando ?.

No necesitaré el `controls`, la idea del audio es utilizarlo futuramente dentro de una función que se ejecute al finalizar un temporizador.

¿Alguna idea del porque no se esta reproduciendo? ¿o deberia buscar otra forma de enlazar el archivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es CORS. El navegador no permite la reproducción de audio/video a menos que el servidor de dicho recurso lo acepte **explícitamente**. Para que aceptarlo, la petición de datos debe incluir el header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` con tu dominio o con un * (admite cualquier petición de cualquier dominio).

Por ejemplo si intentamos reproducir el siguiente video:

```html
<video src="https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" controls="true"></video>
```

obtenemos la siguiente respuesta:

[image: Captura de la consola: header Access-Control-Allow-Origin presente]

Lamentablemente, Google drive no incluye ese header, por lo que no puedes ofrecer el audio desde ahí.

Comment: Entiendo.. Gracias! Excelente explicación! 
En ese caso surge otra duda. ¿Como podria anexar mi audio sin tener que cargar el archivo?
Busque en varios sitios de audio, más no consegui obtener el audio por enlace, solamente descarga.
No veo problema al cargar el archivo en mi visual, mas en CodePen se complico un poco

Comment: añadiéndolo como dato en la URL, usando base64. Pero si el audio es pesado va a ser complicado

Comment: Entiendo amigo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!